# Failure to debug T-SQL or stored procedures

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Sql Server 2008 SP2

In Management Studio 2008 after setting a breakpoint on any piece of T-SQL and presssing debug button:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Failed to start debugger

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values. (System.Data)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

After pressing OK.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
---------------------------
Unable to start program 'MSSQL:://(local)/master/sys/=0'.

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

In Visual Studio 2010

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The Transact-SQL debugging session could not be started on the remote host. Verify that the instance of SQL Server is configured to enable Transact-SQL debugging.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Followed advice in other thread to apply SP2 for SQL Server 2008 without success. Server is actually (local) , don't know why Visual Studio reports it as remote.

Comment: I think you need to make sure DTC is installed and configured... its what enables the debugging in SSMS...

Answer (score 0):

Check that your account running the debugger is a member of the sysadmin role

Also if you are running windows firewall you need to add the ports to the rules list

check this link for more details

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646024.aspx